# How to reinstall missing kernel modules after deletion?

Tags: kernel, linux-headers

The other day I was cleaning some disk space. I deleted some directories with the Linux Kernel headers. Now I see a lot of errors complaining about missing Linux headers. I tried to reinstall them but, can't find them.

I've already researched many commands but, none of them work. This is what I have tried so far:

```
linux@linux:~$ sudo apt-get install uswsusp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libx86-1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libx86-1 uswsusp
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 220 kB of archives.
After this operation, 977 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libx86-1 amd64 1.1+ds1-10.2 [75,2 kB]
Get:2 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 uswsusp amd64 1.0+20120915-6.1build1 [145 kB]
Fetched 220 kB in 1s (297 kB/s)  
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx86-1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 385946 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libx86-1_1.1+ds1-10.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libx86-1:amd64 (1.1+ds1-10.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package uswsusp.
Preparing to unpack .../uswsusp_1.0+20120915-6.1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking uswsusp (1.0+20120915-6.1build1) ...
Setting up libx86-1:amd64 (1.1+ds1-10.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up uswsusp (1.0+20120915-6.1build1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
0depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_x156QB/lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_x156QB/lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

linux@linux:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure uswsusp
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_PgcUvV/lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_PgcUvV/lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

linux@linux:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-4.15.0-46-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0-46.49).
linux-headers-4.15.0-46-generic set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.

linux@linux:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Ign:1 http://mirror.ufscar.br/mint-archive tessa InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                
Hit:3 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:4 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:5 http://mirror.ufscar.br/mint-archive tessa Release                                                                                                                                                                                    
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                       
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hluk/copyq/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                
Hit:9 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                               
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Reading package lists... Done                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnss-myhostname libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler-qt5-1 libpoppler73 libseccomp2 libsystemd0 libudev1 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-damage0 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0
  libxcb-record0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-res0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xkb1 libxcb-xv0 libxcb1 libxcb1-dev poppler-utils systemd systemd-sysv udev
32 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6.053 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16,4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libnss-systemd amd64 237-3ubuntu10.15 [105 kB]
0% [1 libnss-systemd 13,9 kB/105 kB 13%]
Get:2 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 237-3ubuntu10.15 [205 kB]
Get:3 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 systemd amd64 237-3ubuntu10.15 [2.899 kB]
Get:4 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpam-systemd amd64 237-3ubuntu10.15 [108 kB]
Get:5 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libnss-myhostname amd64 237-3ubuntu10.15 [34,4 kB]
Get:6 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 237-3ubuntu10.15 [1.100 kB]
Get:7 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 237-3ubuntu10.15 [54,2 kB]
Get:8 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 systemd-sysv amd64 237-3ubuntu10.15 [12,0 kB]
Get:9 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libseccomp2 amd64 2.3.1-2.1ubuntu4.1 [39,1 kB]
Get:10 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb1-dev amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [80,0 kB]
Get:11 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb1 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [45,5 kB]
Get:12 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-render0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [14,7 kB]
Get:13 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-shm0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [5.600 B]
Get:14 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 libpoppler-qt5-1 amd64 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8 [140 kB]
Get:15 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 poppler-utils amd64 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8 [154 kB]
Get:16 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpoppler-glib8 amd64 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8 [108 kB]
Get:17 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpoppler73 amd64 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8 [799 kB]
Get:18 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-composite0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [5.184 B]
Get:19 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-damage0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [4.872 B]
Get:20 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-dri2-0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [6.920 B]
Get:21 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-dri3-0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [6.568 B]
Get:22 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-glx0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [22,1 kB]
Get:23 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-present0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [5.552 B]
Get:24 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-randr0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [16,4 kB]
Get:25 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-record0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [7.064 B]
Get:26 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-res0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [6.392 B]
Get:27 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-shape0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [5.972 B]
Get:28 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-sync1 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [8.808 B]
Get:29 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-xfixes0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [9.352 B]
Get:30 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-xinerama0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [5.264 B]
Get:31 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-xkb1 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [30,1 kB]
Get:32 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxcb-xv0 amd64 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04 [9.168 B]
Fetched 6.053 kB in 3s (2.331 kB/s)    
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnss-systemd_237-3ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15) over (237-3ubuntu10.13) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libsystemd0_237-3ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15) over (237-3ubuntu10.13) ...
Setting up libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15) ...
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_237-3ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (237-3ubuntu10.15) over (237-3ubuntu10.13) ...
Setting up systemd (237-3ubuntu10.15) ...
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpam-systemd_237-3ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15) over (237-3ubuntu10.13) ...
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15) ...
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnss-myhostname_237-3ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnss-myhostname:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15) over (237-3ubuntu10.13) ...
Preparing to unpack .../udev_237-3ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (237-3ubuntu10.15) over (237-3ubuntu10.13) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_237-3ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15) over (237-3ubuntu10.13) ...
Setting up libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15) ...
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd-sysv_237-3ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-sysv (237-3ubuntu10.15) over (237-3ubuntu10.13) ...
Setting up systemd-sysv (237-3ubuntu10.15) ...
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libseccomp2_2.3.1-2.1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libseccomp2:amd64 (2.3.1-2.1ubuntu4.1) over (2.3.1-2.1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up libseccomp2:amd64 (2.3.1-2.1ubuntu4.1) ...
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxcb1-dev_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb1-dev:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libxcb1_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb1:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Setting up libxcb1:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxcb-render0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-render0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-render0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxcb-shm0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-shm0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-shm0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libpoppler-qt5-1_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8) over (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-poppler-utils_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking poppler-utils (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8) over (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-libpoppler-glib8_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpoppler-glib8:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8) over (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-libpoppler73_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpoppler73:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8) over (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libxcb-composite0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-composite0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libxcb-damage0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-damage0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libxcb-dri2-0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-dri2-0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libxcb-dri3-0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-dri3-0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libxcb-glx0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-glx0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libxcb-present0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-present0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-libxcb-randr0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-randr0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-libxcb-record0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-record0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-libxcb-res0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-res0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-libxcb-shape0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-shape0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-libxcb-sync1_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-sync1:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-libxcb-xfixes0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-xfixes0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-libxcb-xinerama0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-xinerama0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-libxcb-xkb1_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-xkb1:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-libxcb-xv0_1.13-2~ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-xv0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) over (1.13-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-xinerama0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libxcb-present0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15) ...
Setting up libxcb-composite0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libxcb-dri2-0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libxcb-dri3-0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libxcb-glx0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libxcb-randr0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libxcb-xfixes0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Setting up libnss-myhostname:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15) ...
Setting up libxcb-res0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libxcb-record0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libxcb-damage0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libxcb-sync1:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libpoppler73:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up udev (237-3ubuntu10.15) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libxcb-xv0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.15) ...
Setting up libxcb-shape0:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libxcb1-dev:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libxcb-xkb1:amd64 (1.13-2~ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libpoppler-glib8:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8) ...
Setting up poppler-utils (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8) ...
Setting up libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu2.8) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_TKdkq1/lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_TKdkq1/lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...

linux@linux:~$ sudo apt install linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0-46.49).
linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

linux@linux:~$ sudo apt install linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic --reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 7.904 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic amd64 4.15.0-46.49 [7.904 kB]
Fetched 7.904 kB in 3s (3.111 kB/s)                        
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic_4.15.0-46.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (4.15.0-46.49) over (4.15.0-46.49) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (4.15.0-46.49) ...
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

linux@linux:~$ sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic.
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-46-generic depends on linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic | linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-46-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic is to be removed.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-46-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic

linux@linux:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0-46.49).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (4.15.0-46.49) ...
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

linux@linux:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (4.15.0-46.49) ...
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

linux@linux:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (4.15.0-46.49) ...
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

linux@linux:~$ sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (4.15.0-46.49) ...
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

linux@linux:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2.376 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirror.ufscar.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 4.15.0.46.48 [2.376 B]
Fetched 2.376 B in 0s (10,5 kB/s)                 
(Reading database ... 385977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic_4.15.0.46.48_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.46.48) over (4.15.0.46.48) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (4.15.0-46.49) ...
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.46.48) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: If the header packages are still marked as installed in apt, you might have to "uninstall" them with and then install them again.

Answer (score 5):

From: [How to install Linux Kernel headers on Debian or Ubuntu](https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/how-install-linux-kernel-headers-debian-or-ubuntu.html)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I already ran this command, if you look into the log output I presented, and you will notice the problem persists on the next commands which come after.

Comment: @user I added `--reinstall` option to force complete installation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @WinEunuuchs2Unix I also found I had to navigate to `/var/lib/dpkg/info`, search for "linux-", and then delete any files that were corrupted - you can tell by them not having the normal 'lines-of-text' icon but rather 0's and 1's.

I hope this helps someone else who has been getting nowhere for ages, like me!